# Error importing seaborn module: AttributeError

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn, google-colaboratory

I installed seaborn as

```
!pip install seaborn --upgrade --quiet
```

but when i tried to import it using

```
import seaborn as sns
```

I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-a84c0541e888> in <module>
----> 1 import seaborn as sns

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    311             x = ones(2, dtype=float32)
    312             if not abs(x.dot(x) - float32(2.0)) < 1e-5:
--> 313                 raise AssertionError()
    314         except AssertionError:
    315             msg = ("The current Numpy installation ({!r}) fails to "

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'
```

I tried uninstalling and re-installing but it didn't work.
Also, closed and started the notebook but it issue remains same.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall numpy and reinstall it?

Comment: Maybe this is related to [this issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3192) where the suggested workaround is to downgrade numpy from version 1.24.0, version 1.23.5.

Comment: @JohanC looks unrelated, but does look like a problem with the numpy installation not the seaborn installation

Comment: @enslaved_programmer yeah, i tried but issue remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy seems missing a decorator `_no_nep50_warning` to issue optional warnings. The purpose of this decorator is documented at https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0050-scalar-promotion.html
The problem experienced is a version incompatibility that the package maintainers should resolve, for my environment it involves other packages, like sklearn, too.

For this specific issue, one can try manually downgrade numpy by

```bash
!pip install numpy==1.23.3 --quiet --ignore-installed
```

but I wouldn't recommend that. One should use a package manager to resolve compatibility issues.

Assume you can live without that optional feature of numpy and understand which warnings you are going to miss. Then the following snippet puts a dummy replacement of the decorator into numpy thus allowing the import of seaborn:

```py
import numpy as np
def dummy_npwarn_decorator_factory():
  def npwarn_decorator(x):
    return x
  return npwarn_decorator
np._no_nep50_warning = getattr(np, '_no_nep50_warning', dummy_npwarn_decorator_factory)

import seaborn as sns  # now should work
```

This code does not alter the decorator if it exist in numpy.