# module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'

Tags: python, embedding, langchain

When load HuggingFaceEmbeddings, always shows error like below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-04d1583103a5> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install --force-reinstall numpy==1.24.0')
----> 2 embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
      3     model_name="oshizo/sbert-jsnli-luke-japanese-base-lite"
      4 )

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    309         """
    310         try:
--> 311             x = ones(2, dtype=float32)
    312             if not abs(x.dot(x) - float32(2.0)) < 1e-5:
    313                 raise AssertionError()

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'
```

I tried to downgrade numpy version to

```
1.25.2 -> 1.24.4 -> 1.24.2 -> 1.24.1 -> 1.24.0
```

But always same errors happen. and googles has no answer about this.
If anyone know how to fixing it this problem... please tell me any information,

Heres my pip installed source code.
numpy versions 1.24.0 was trying to downgrade version last time.

```
!pip install --force-reinstall numpy==1.24.0
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="intfloat/multilingual-e5-large"
)
```

Heres my pip list below

```
Package                          Version
-------------------------------- ---------------------
absl-py                          1.4.0
accelerate                       0.22.0
aiohttp                          3.8.5
aiosignal                        1.3.1
alabaster                        0.7.13
albumentations                   1.3.1
altair                           4.2.2
annotated-types                  0.5.0
anyio                            3.7.1
appdirs                          1.4.4
argon2-cffi                      23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings             21.2.0
array-record                     0.4.1
arviz                            0.15.1
astropy                          5.3.2
astunparse                       1.6.3
async-timeout                    4.0.3
attrs                            23.1.0
audioread                        3.0.0
autograd                         1.6.2
Babel                            2.12.1
backcall                         0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                   4.11.2
bleach                           6.0.0
blinker                          1.4
blis                             0.7.10
blosc2                           2.0.0
bokeh                            3.2.2
boto3                            1.28.43
botocore                         1.31.43
bqplot                           0.12.40
branca                           0.6.0
build                            1.0.0
CacheControl                     0.13.1
cachetools                       5.3.1
catalogue                        2.0.9
certifi                          2023.7.22
cffi                             1.15.1
chardet                          5.2.0
charset-normalizer               3.2.0
chex                             0.1.7
click                            8.1.7
click-plugins                    1.1.1
cligj                            0.7.2
cloudpickle                      2.2.1
cmake                            3.27.2
cmdstanpy                        1.1.0
colorcet                         3.0.1
colorlover                       0.3.0
colour                           0.1.5
community                        1.0.0b1
confection                       0.1.1
cons                             0.4.6
contextlib2                      21.6.0
contourpy                        1.1.0
convertdate                      2.4.0
cryptography                     41.0.3
cufflinks                        0.17.3
cupy-cuda11x                     11.0.0
cvxopt                           1.3.2
cvxpy                            1.3.2
cycler                           0.11.0
cymem                            2.0.7
Cython                           0.29.36
dask                             2023.8.1
dataclasses-json                 0.5.14
datascience                      0.17.6
db-dtypes                        1.1.1
dbus-python                      1.2.18
debugpy                          1.6.6
decorator                        4.4.2
defusedxml                       0.7.1
diskcache                        5.6.3
distributed                      2023.8.1
distro                           1.7.0
dlib                             19.24.2
dm-tree                          0.1.8
docutils                         0.18.1
dopamine-rl                      4.0.6
duckdb                           0.8.1
earthengine-api                  0.1.367
easydict                         1.10
ecos                             2.0.12
editdistance                     0.6.2
eerepr                           0.0.4
en-core-web-sm                   3.6.0
entrypoints                      0.4
ephem                            4.1.4
et-xmlfile                       1.1.0
etils                            1.4.1
etuples                          0.3.9
exceptiongroup                   1.1.3
faiss-gpu                        1.7.2
fastai                           2.7.12
fastcore                         1.5.29
fastdownload                     0.0.7
fastjsonschema                   2.18.0
fastprogress                     1.0.3
fastrlock                        0.8.2
filelock                         3.12.3
Fiona                            1.9.4.post1
firebase-admin                   5.3.0
Flask                            2.2.5
flatbuffers                      23.5.26
flax                             0.7.2
folium                           0.14.0
fonttools                        4.42.1
frozendict                       2.3.8
frozenlist                       1.4.0
fsspec                           2023.6.0
future                           0.18.3
gast                             0.4.0
gcsfs                            2023.6.0
GDAL                             3.4.3
gdown                            4.6.6
geemap                           0.25.0
gensim                           4.3.2
geocoder                         1.38.1
geographiclib                    2.0
geopandas                        0.13.2
geopy                            2.3.0
gin-config                       0.5.0
glob2                            0.7
google                           2.0.3
google-api-core                  2.11.1
google-api-python-client         2.84.0
google-auth                      2.17.3
google-auth-httplib2             0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib             1.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery            3.10.0
google-cloud-bigquery-connection 1.12.1
google-cloud-bigquery-storage    2.22.0
google-cloud-core                2.3.3
google-cloud-datastore           2.15.2
google-cloud-firestore           2.11.1
google-cloud-functions           1.13.2
google-cloud-language            2.9.1
google-cloud-storage             2.8.0
google-cloud-translate           3.11.3
google-colab                     1.0.0
google-crc32c                    1.5.0
google-pasta                     0.2.0
google-resumable-media           2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos         1.60.0
googledrivedownloader            0.4
graphviz                         0.20.1
greenlet                         2.0.2
grpc-google-iam-v1               0.12.6
grpcio                           1.57.0
grpcio-status                    1.48.2
gspread                          3.4.2
gspread-dataframe                3.3.1
gym                              0.25.2
gym-notices                      0.0.8
h5netcdf                         1.2.0
h5py                             3.9.0
holidays                         0.32
holoviews                        1.17.1
html5lib                         1.1
httpimport                       1.3.1
httplib2                         0.22.0
huggingface-hub                  0.16.4
humanize                         4.7.0
hyperopt                         0.2.7
idna                             3.4
imageio                          2.31.3
imageio-ffmpeg                   0.4.8
imagesize                        1.4.1
imbalanced-learn                 0.10.1
imgaug                           0.4.0
importlib-metadata               6.8.0
importlib-resources              6.0.1
imutils                          0.5.4
inflect                          7.0.0
iniconfig                        2.0.0
intel-openmp                     2023.2.0
ipyevents                        2.0.2
ipyfilechooser                   0.6.0
ipykernel                        5.5.6
ipyleaflet                       0.17.3
ipython                          7.34.0
ipython-genutils                 0.2.0
ipython-sql                      0.5.0
ipytree                          0.2.2
ipywidgets                       7.7.1
itsdangerous                     2.1.2
jax                              0.4.14
jaxlib                           0.4.14+cuda11.cudnn86
jeepney                          0.7.1
jieba                            0.42.1
Jinja2                           3.1.2
jmespath                         1.0.1
joblib                           1.3.2
jsonpickle                       3.0.2
jsonschema                       4.19.0
jsonschema-specifications        2023.7.1
jupyter-client                   6.1.12
jupyter-console                  6.1.0
jupyter_core                     5.3.1
jupyter-server                   1.24.0
jupyterlab-pygments              0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets               3.0.8
kaggle                           1.5.16
keras                            2.12.0
keyring                          23.5.0
kiwisolver                       1.4.5
langchain                        0.0.284
langcodes                        3.3.0
langsmith                        0.0.33
launchpadlib                     1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient               0.14.4
lazr.uri                         1.0.6
lazy_loader                      0.3
libclang                         16.0.6
librosa                          0.10.1
lightgbm                         4.0.0
linkify-it-py                    2.0.2
lit                              16.0.6
llama-cpp-python                 0.1.83
llvmlite                         0.39.1
locket                           1.0.0
logical-unification              0.4.6
LunarCalendar                    0.0.9
lxml                             4.9.3
Markdown                         3.4.4
markdown-it-py                   3.0.0
MarkupSafe                       2.1.3
marshmallow                      3.20.1
matplotlib                       3.7.1
matplotlib-inline                0.1.6
matplotlib-venn                  0.11.9
mdit-py-plugins                  0.4.0
mdurl                            0.1.2
miniKanren                       1.0.3
missingno                        0.5.2
mistune                          0.8.4
mizani                           0.9.3
mkl                              2023.2.0
ml-dtypes                        0.2.0
mlxtend                          0.22.0
more-itertools                   10.1.0
moviepy                          1.0.3
mpmath                           1.3.0
msgpack                          1.0.5
multidict                        6.0.4
multipledispatch                 1.0.0
multitasking                     0.0.11
murmurhash                       1.0.9
music21                          9.1.0
mypy-extensions                  1.0.0
natsort                          8.4.0
nbclassic                        1.0.0
nbclient                         0.8.0
nbconvert                        6.5.4
nbformat                         5.9.2
nest-asyncio                     1.5.7
networkx                         3.1
nibabel                          4.0.2
nltk                             3.8.1
notebook                         6.5.5
notebook_shim                    0.2.3
numba                            0.56.4
numexpr                          2.8.5
numpy                            1.24.0
oauth2client                     4.1.3
oauthlib                         3.2.2
openai                           0.28.0
opencv-contrib-python            4.8.0.76
opencv-python                    4.8.0.76
opencv-python-headless           4.8.0.76
openpyxl                         3.1.2
opt-einsum                       3.3.0
optax                            0.1.7
orbax-checkpoint                 0.3.5
osqp                             0.6.2.post8
packaging                        23.1
pandas                           1.5.3
pandas-datareader                0.10.0
pandas-gbq                       0.17.9
pandocfilters                    1.5.0
panel                            1.2.2
param                            1.13.0
parso                            0.8.3
partd                            1.4.0
pathlib                          1.0.1
pathy                            0.10.2
patsy                            0.5.3
pexpect                          4.8.0
pickleshare                      0.7.5
Pillow                           9.4.0
pip                              23.2.1
pip-tools                        6.13.0
platformdirs                     3.10.0
plotly                           5.15.0
plotnine                         0.12.3
pluggy                           1.3.0
polars                           0.17.3
pooch                            1.7.0
portpicker                       1.5.2
prefetch-generator               1.0.3
preshed                          3.0.8
prettytable                      3.8.0
proglog                          0.1.10
progressbar2                     4.2.0
prometheus-client                0.17.1
promise                          2.3
prompt-toolkit                   3.0.39
prophet                          1.1.4
proto-plus                       1.22.3
protobuf                         3.20.3
psutil                           5.9.5
psycopg2                         2.9.7
ptyprocess                       0.7.0
py-cpuinfo                       9.0.0
py4j                             0.10.9.7
pyarrow                          9.0.0
pyasn1                           0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                   0.3.0
pycocotools                      2.0.7
pycparser                        2.21
pyct                             0.5.0
pydantic                         2.3.0
pydantic_core                    2.6.3
pydata-google-auth               1.8.2
pydot                            1.4.2
pydot-ng                         2.0.0
pydotplus                        2.0.2
PyDrive                          1.3.1
PyDrive2                         1.6.3
pyerfa                           2.0.0.3
pygame                           2.5.1
Pygments                         2.16.1
PyGObject                        3.42.1
PyJWT                            2.3.0
pymc                             5.7.2
PyMeeus                          0.5.12
PyMuPDF                          1.23.3
PyMuPDFb                         1.23.3
pymystem3                        0.2.0
PyOpenGL                         3.1.7
pyOpenSSL                        23.2.0
pyparsing                        3.1.1
pyperclip                        1.8.2
pyproj                           3.6.0
pyproject_hooks                  1.0.0
pyshp                            2.3.1
PySocks                          1.7.1
pytensor                         2.14.2
pytest                           7.4.1
python-apt                       0.0.0
python-box                       7.1.1
python-dateutil                  2.8.2
python-louvain                   0.16
python-slugify                   8.0.1
python-utils                     3.7.0
pytz                             2023.3.post1
pyviz_comms                      3.0.0
PyWavelets                       1.4.1
PyYAML                           6.0.1
pyzmq                            23.2.1
qdldl                            0.1.7.post0
qudida                           0.0.4
ratelim                          0.1.6
referencing                      0.30.2
regex                            2023.6.3
requests                         2.31.0
requests-oauthlib                1.3.1
requirements-parser              0.5.0
rich                             13.5.2
rpds-py                          0.10.2
rpy2                             3.4.2
rsa                              4.9
s3transfer                       0.6.2
safetensors                      0.3.3
scikit-image                     0.19.3
scikit-learn                     1.2.2
scipy                            1.10.1
scooby                           0.7.2
scs                              3.2.3
seaborn                          0.12.2
SecretStorage                    3.3.1
Send2Trash                       1.8.2
sentence-transformers            2.2.2
sentencepiece                    0.1.99
setuptools                       67.7.2
shapely                          2.0.1
six                              1.16.0
sklearn-pandas                   2.2.0
smart-open                       6.3.0
sniffio                          1.3.0
snowballstemmer                  2.2.0
sortedcontainers                 2.4.0
soundfile                        0.12.1
soupsieve                        2.5
soxr                             0.3.6
spacy                            3.6.1
spacy-legacy                     3.0.12
spacy-loggers                    1.0.4
Sphinx                           5.0.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp          1.0.7
sphinxcontrib-devhelp            1.0.5
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp           2.0.4
sphinxcontrib-jsmath             1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp             1.0.6
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml    1.1.9
SQLAlchemy                       2.0.20
sqlparse                         0.4.4
srsly                            2.4.7
statsmodels                      0.14.0
sympy                            1.12
tables                           3.8.0
tabulate                         0.9.0
tbb                              2021.10.0
tblib                            2.0.0
tenacity                         8.2.3
tensorboard                      2.12.3
tensorboard-data-server          0.7.1
tensorflow                       2.12.0
tensorflow-datasets              4.9.2
tensorflow-estimator             2.12.0
tensorflow-gcs-config            2.12.0
tensorflow-hub                   0.14.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem     0.33.0
tensorflow-metadata              1.14.0
tensorflow-probability           0.20.1
tensorstore                      0.1.41
termcolor                        2.3.0
terminado                        0.17.1
text-unidecode                   1.3
textblob                         0.17.1
tf-slim                          1.1.0
thinc                            8.1.12
threadpoolctl                    3.2.0
tifffile                         2023.8.30
tinycss2                         1.2.1
tokenizers                       0.13.3
toml                             0.10.2
tomli                            2.0.1
toolz                            0.12.0
torch                            2.0.1+cu118
torchaudio                       2.0.2+cu118
torchdata                        0.6.1
torchsummary                     1.5.1
torchtext                        0.15.2
torchvision                      0.15.2+cu118
tornado                          6.3.2
tqdm                             4.66.1
traitlets                        5.7.1
traittypes                       0.2.1
transformers                     4.33.1
triton                           2.0.0
tweepy                           4.13.0
typer                            0.9.0
types-setuptools                 68.1.0.1
typing_extensions                4.7.1
typing-inspect                   0.9.0
tzlocal                          5.0.1
uc-micro-py                      1.0.2
uritemplate                      4.1.1
urllib3                          1.26.16
vega-datasets                    0.9.0
wadllib                          1.3.6
wasabi                           1.1.2
wcwidth                          0.2.6
webcolors                        1.13
webencodings                     0.5.1
websocket-client                 1.6.2
Werkzeug                         2.3.7
wheel                            0.41.2
widgetsnbextension               3.6.5
wordcloud                        1.9.2
wrapt                            1.14.1
xarray                           2023.7.0
xarray-einstats                  0.6.0
xgboost                          1.7.6
xlrd                             2.0.1
xyzservices                      2023.7.0
yarl                             1.9.2
yellowbrick                      1.5
yfinance                         0.2.28
zict                             3.0.0
zipp                             3.16.2
```

Comment: share result of pip list and code which is throwing this error

Comment: @ZKS Thanks for reply. and I added ```pip list``` and code

Comment: Maybe try da downgrade langchain...

Comment: downgraded to 0.0.275 about langchain but same.... my numpy is probablly sucks?

Comment: Hey! its only things happned on google colab!! Nothing happen on local windows python. maybe python versions problem?

Comment: colab is 3.10.12 and local windows is 3.11.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open fresh collab editor and run each command

```
#this is minimum pre-requisites
pip install langchain
pip install sentence-transformers
```

Code

```
 from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
  model_name="intfloat/multilingual-e5-large"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code after refresh my colab, then did it work fine! Then my colab attent to me your environment reached gpu limit, sadge. funny...

Comment: change this multilingual-e5-large to multilingual-e5-small while you work (dev mode). Large models will always have resources crunch when you are using cloud resources.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
def dummy_npwarn_decorator_factory():
  def npwarn_decorator(x):
    return x
  return npwarn_decorator
np._no_nep50_warning = getattr(np, '_no_nep50_warning', dummy_npwarn_decorator_factory)
```

[Error importing seaborn module: AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918614/error-importing-seaborn-module-attributeerror)